# Javascript handling Memory leak issue by v8 engine

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, v8

In Javascript, there is a memory leak if we remove event listeners on the parent DOM node, without removing those on child nodes explicitly.

Is that a bug in the V8 engine ?

Is there any specific reason why the V8 does not remove child references automatically ?

Comment: you might want to add V8 to the title and tags if you're sure this is V8-related.

Answer (score 2):

removeEventListener only removes event listeners on the node you call it on